# How am I supposed to use pandas functions?

Tags: python, pandas

Let data be a giant pandas dataframe. It has many functions. The functions do not modify in place but return a new dataframe. How then am I supposed to perform multiple operations, to maximize performance?

For example, say I want to do

`data = data.method1().method2().method()`

where method1 could be `set_index`, and so on.

Is this the way you are supposed to do it? My wory is that pandas creates a copy every time I call a method, so that there are 3 copies being made of my data in the above, when in reality, all I want is to modify the original one.

So is it faster to say

```
data = data.method1(inplace=True)
data = data.method2(inplace=True)
data = data.method3(inplace=True)
```

This is just way too verbose for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, i.e applying methods one after the other. Since you overwrite data, you are not creating 3 copies, but only keeping one copy

```py
data = data.method1().method2().method()
```

However regarding your second example, the general rule is to either write over the existing dataframe or do it "inplace", but not both at the same time

```py
data = data.method1()
```

or

```py
data.method1(inplace=True)
```